# How to find all inputs elements inside custom directive & based on some condition set readonly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, angular-directive, jqlite

```
(function() {
  "use strict";

  angular
    .module("app")
    .directive("myCustomDirective", myCustomDirective);

  myCustomDirective.$inject = ["$compile"];

  function myCustomDirective($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: "E",
      templateUrl: "app/views/template.html",
      scope: {
        ui: '=info',
        index: '=',
      },
      compile: function(tElem, tAttrs) {
        // console.log(': compile => ' + tElem.html());
        return {
          pre: function(scope, iElem, iAttrs) {},
          post: function(scope, iElem, iAttrs) {
            //console.log(scope);
            //console.log(iElem[0].innerHTML);
          }
        }
      }

      //controller: 'd3PhaseController'
    };
  }
}());
```

Directive template

```
<div class="col-md-6">
   <textarea class="form-control" ng-required="true"></textarea>
</div>
```

Controller

```
vm = {
    "SomeId" : "This id will fetched from the server"
};
```

> What I am looking for is  if `vm.SomeId == 1` then find all the input
>   elements in the custom directive & make it readonly

Yes I know I could easily put

```
<textarea class="form-control"  ng-attr-readonly="{{some check}}"></textarea>
```

But this is kind of an overhead because I have n such controllers & n such directives.